# Why is htaccess redirect not working when URL variable is NOT included?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a page called names.php that list out most popular names by year.

The main menu link goes www.example.com/most-popular-names/2017 since it's the current year.

That "clean" URL gets redirected via .htaccess with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?most-popular-names/([^/]+)/?$ /names.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This all works fine.  However, if someone goes to:

```
www.example.com/most-popular-names (with no year specified)
```

It goes to a 404 page.  Shouldn't it still go to names.php?  On names.php I have the code below that says if no year is set, just use the current year, but it's 404'ing so I assume it's never reaching names.php at all.

```
$currentyear=date('Y');
if (!isset($_GET['year'])) {  //if not set for some reason, default to current year
    $theyear=$currentyear;
} else { 
    $theyear=$_GET['year'];
}
```

Is there a better/different way to write the rewrite rule to handle this situation?  I could add a separate rewrite rule to handle the "no year" URL possibily, but that seems wrong/inefficent to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean way to do it is make the variable part of the URL optional with ?:

```
RewriteRule ^/?most-popular-names/?([^/]+)?$ names.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I replaced my RewriteRule with this one and it now kicks a "Error 500 - Internal Server Error".

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: I was mistaken, had a typo.  Yours is working except for one aspect.  It's seeing $_GET['year'] as "/(the year)".  So if url ends with /2017, $_GET['year'] is being seen as "/2017" instead of just "2017".  Previously, it wasn't including the "/".  I can easily add a little function to strip off the leading slash, but wanted to mention in case there is a way to prevent that in the rewriterule

Comment: Glad it worked. I edited the answer anyway to make the leading slash part of the other group. Now it's optional and you'll also get your year cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another rule to handle that. Something that handles the url with and without the ending slash and NO params. Something like:

```
Rewrite Rule ^/?most-popular-names[/].$ /names.php [L,QSA]
```